Issue to identify minimum number of vehicles to be used in VRP PDTW
Which part of the code do I add this function if I want to add a fixed cost to all vehicles such that the solution uses the minimum number of vehicles needed for VRP with pickup & delivery and time window?
for vehicle_id in range(num_vehicles):
routing.SetFixedCostOfVehicle(
vehicle_costs[vehicle_id], vehicle_id)
when this is the main part the code
def main():
"""Solve the CVRP problem."""
# Instantiate the data problem.
data = create_data_model()
# The inputs to RoutingIndexManager
# Create the routing index manager.
manager = pywrapcp.RoutingIndexManager(
len(data["distance_matrix"]), data["num_vehicles"], data["depot"]
)
    # Create Routing Model.
routing = pywrapcp.RoutingModel(manager)

  #The callback accepts two indices, from_index and to_index, and returns the corresponding entry of the distance matrix.
def distance_callback(from_index, to_index):
    """Returns the distance between the two nodes."""
    # Convert from routing variable Index to distance matrix NodeIndex.
    from_node = manager.IndexToNode(from_index)
    to_node = manager.IndexToNode(to_index)
    return data["distance_matrix"][from_node][to_node]
#The following function creates the callback and registers it with the solver as transit_callback_index.
transit_callback_index = routing.RegisterTransitCallback(distance_callback)

# Define cost of each arc.
# The arc cost evaluator tells the solver how to calculate the cost of travel between any two locations — in other words, the cost of the edge (or arc) joining them in the graph for the problem.
routing.SetArcCostEvaluatorOfAllVehicles(transit_callback_index)

  # Add Distance constraint.
dimension_name = "Distance"
routing.AddDimension(
    transit_callback_index,        # The index for the callback that returns the quantity
    0,  # no slack # Specifies Maximum for the slack varaible (usually used in waiting time or demands)
    data['vehicle_max_distance'],  # maximum distance per vehicle #Maximum for the total quantity accumulated along each route.
    True,  # start cumul to zero #Boolean value. If true, the cumulative value of the quantity starts at 0.
    dimension_name, # Dimension name- String for the name for the dimension which you can use to access the variables elsewhere in the program
)
distance_dimension = routing.GetDimensionOrDie(dimension_name)
distance_dimension.SetGlobalSpanCostCoefficient(100)
# Define Transportation Requests.
for request in data["pickups_deliveries"]:
    pickup_index = manager.NodeToIndex(request[0])
    delivery_index = manager.NodeToIndex(request[1])
    routing.AddPickupAndDelivery(pickup_index, delivery_index)
    routing.solver().Add(
        routing.VehicleVar(pickup_index) == routing.VehicleVar(delivery_index)
    )
  
    routing.solver().Add(
        distance_dimension.CumulVar(pickup_index)
        <= distance_dimension.CumulVar(delivery_index)
    )

# Add Capacity constraint.
def demand_callback(from_index):
    """Returns the demand of the node."""
    # Convert from routing variable Index to demands NodeIndex.
    from_node = manager.IndexToNode(from_index)
    return data["demands"][from_node]

demand_callback_index = routing.RegisterUnaryTransitCallback(demand_callback)

# But AddDimensionWithVehicleCapacity handles the more general case in which different vehicles have different capacities.
routing.AddDimension(
    demand_callback_index,
    0,  # null capacity slack
    data["vehicle_capacity"],  # vehicle maximum capacities
    True,  # start cumul to zero
    "Capacity",
)

# Create and register a transit callback.
def time_callback(from_index, to_index):
    """Returns the travel time between the two nodes."""
    # Convert from routing variable Index to time matrix NodeIndex.
    from_node = manager.IndexToNode(from_index)
    to_node = manager.IndexToNode(to_index)
    return data["distance_matrix"][from_node][to_node] + data['vehicle_load_unload_time']

time_callback_index = routing.RegisterTransitCallback(time_callback)

# Add Time Windows constraint.
time = "Time"
max_time = data['vehicle_max_time']
routing.AddDimension(
    time_callback_index,
    max_time,  # allow waiting time
    max_time,  # maximum time per vehicle
    False,  # Don't force start cumul to zero since we are giving TW to start nodes.
    time,
)
time_dimension = routing.GetDimensionOrDie(time)
# Add time window constraints for each location except depot.
for location_idx, time_window in enumerate(data["time_windows"]):
    if location_idx == data["depot"]:
        continue
    index = manager.NodeToIndex(location_idx)
    time_dimension.CumulVar(index).SetRange(time_window[0], time_window[1])
# Add time window constraints for each vehicle start node.
depot_idx = data["depot"]
for vehicle_id in range(data["num_vehicles"]):
    index = routing.Start(vehicle_id)
    time_dimension.CumulVar(index).SetRange(
        data["time_windows"][depot_idx][0], data["time_windows"][depot_idx][1]
    )


search_parameters = pywrapcp.DefaultRoutingSearchParameters()
# The code below shows how to set a solution limit of 100 for a search.
#search_parameters.solution_limit = 100
search_parameters.first_solution_strategy = (
    routing_enums_pb2.FirstSolutionStrategy.PATH_CHEAPEST_ARC
)
search_parameters.local_search_metaheuristic = (
    routing_enums_pb2.LocalSearchMetaheuristic.GUIDED_LOCAL_SEARCH
)
search_parameters.time_limit.FromSeconds(120)

# Solve the problem.
solution = routing.SolveWithParameters(search_parameters)

Need help with specifying the part of the code where i can use the function

It doesn't matter as long as it's after solver-creation (RoutingModel) but before solve (SolveWithParameters) assuming vehicle_costs and vehicle_id are "ready".
